# Expected Value: Balls and bins

Tags: probability

> Suppose that $n$ balls are tossed into $10$ bins so that each ball is equally likely to fall into any of the bins and tosses are independent. What is the expected number of tosses so that $4$ bins have balls in them?

Here is my approach:

Let $X$ be the random variable equal to the number of tosses expected until $4$ bins have balls in them. Since the random variable has a geometric distribution with parameter $p$, then $E(X) = 1/p$

The first ball can be tossed into any one of the $10$ bins. The second ball must be tossed into one of the remaining $9$ bins. The third ball must be tossed into one of the remaining $8$ bins and the fourth ball must be tossed into one of the remaining $7$ bins.

I calculated the expected value as:
$$E(x) = \frac{10}{10} + \frac{10}{9} + \frac{10}{8} + \frac{10}{7} = 4.79$$
$4.79$ tosses is expected until $4$ bins have balls in them. Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Why the second ball must be tossed into one of the remaining 9 bins? This seems to contradict the "equally like and independent" clause stated at the beginning of your post.

Comment: @MatthewPilling I agree with you that this isn't well expressed, but I think the idea is that after you toss your first ball, the probability of a "good" second toss is $\frac{9}{10}$ so the expected number of tosses necessary to "hit" a second bin is $\frac{10}{9}$.  The same reasoning applies to the third and fourth bins.

Comment: @RobertShore I'll have to chew on this one a bit. My objection to your line of reasoning is based off the fact that we're only tossing a *finite* number of balls into these ten bins. If we had an infinite supply of balls and tossed them into these bins until we observed exactly four non$-$empty bins, I would definitely agree with your perspective. But that's not the case here.

Comment: @MatthewPilling You're right.  The original post should specify that $n \gt \gt 4$ for the result to be approximately true.

Answer (score 1):

You approach is right if $n = \infty$.

In that case, you can write

$$ T= T_1 + T_2 + T_3 + T_4$$
where $T$ is the needed number of tosses, and $T_i$ is the number of tosses to fill the $i-$th bin, just after the $i-1$ bin was filled. Applyting linearity of expectation and seeing that each $T_i$ follows a geometric distribution you get the result.

If you don't stop at $4$ but proceed until you get all the bins fill, you get the [coupon collector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem), which is solved in the same way.

The result can be written as

$$ 
\begin{align}
P&=10 ( \frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{7}) \\
 &= 10 ( H_{10} - H_{6}) \\
\end{align}
$$

where $H_n$ is the harmonic number.

---

If $n$ is finite, then the problem is ill defined, because the event of interest might not happen. One could reformulate: compute the expected number of tosses to fill $4$ bins given that after $n$ tosses at least $4$ bins were occupied. That would be rather messy.

Answer (score 1):

As @leonbloy remarked this problem is ill posed. We can slightly modify this probability experiment so that the expectation you seek is well$-$defined.

Consider the probability experiment of tossing balls into bins until exactly four bins contain at least one ball OR until you run out of balls. Take $K\in \{4,...,n\}$ as the number of times you toss the ball. If $p_K$ is the pmf of $K$ then for $4 \leq k \leq n-1$ we have $$p_{K}(k)=\sum_{a,b,c\in \mathbb{N}:a+b+c=k-1}\Big[(0.1)^{a-1}\cdot(0.9)\cdot(0.2)^{b-1}\cdot (0.8)\cdot(0.3)^{c-1}\cdot(0.7)\Big]$$ The above expression reduces to $$p_K(k)=\frac{126}{5}\cdot (0.3)^{k-2}\Big[3^{2-k}+1-4.5\cdot (2/3)^k\Big]$$ Meanwhile, $$p_{K}(n)=1-\sum_{k=4}^{n-1}p_{K}(k)=\frac{25}{10^n}\Big[16\cdot 3^n-63\cdot 2^n+112\Big]$$ Hence $$\mathbb{E}(K)=\sum_{k=4}^nkp_{K}(k)=\frac{1}{252\cdot 10^n}\left(1260n\left(2^{n}\cdot63-8\cdot3^{n+1}-56\right)+99225\cdot2^{n}+1207\cdot10^{n}-1600\cdot3^{\left(n+3\right)}-78400\right)+\frac{25n}{10^{n}}\left(16\cdot3^{n}-63\cdot2^{n}+112\right)$$ Notice  $\mathbb{E}(K)\approx 4.79$ when $n$ is large.